# Book Recommendations on Cadence OrCAD

Tags: books, orcad

I was wondering which books on Cadence OrCAD (or Cadence products in general) are good for for reference use and/or have substantial focus on device modelling and simulation.

Currently I am using this book, *Complete PCB Design Using OrCad Capture and Layout* by Kraig Mitzner but would like to know other people's preferences.

Comment: I'll second Kraig Mitzner's book.

Answer (score 8):

I've compiled a list of books, with brief descriptions of their coverage and intended readership, relating to spice simulation at

http://www.macspice.com/books

several of these may be useful to you. They include:

## Elementary SPICE

> - *The SPICE Book*  By Andrei Vladimirescu.

## Intermediate SPICE

> - *Inside Spice*  By Ron M. Kielkowski.
> - *The Designer's Guide to SPICE and Spectre*  By Ken Kundert.
> - *High Speed A/D Converters - Understanding Data Converters Through SPICE* By Alfi Moscovici.
> - *SPICE Circuit Handbook* By Steven M. Sandler.
> - *Circuit Simulation with SPICE OPUS* By Tadej Tuma and Árpád Bürmen.

## Advanced Spice

> - *Switch-Mode Power Supplies - Spice Simulations and Practical Designs* By Christophe P. Basso.
> - *Switch-Mode Power Supply SPICE Cookbook* By Christopher Basso.
> - *VLSI Circuit Simulation and Optimization* By V. Litovski and M. Zwolinski.
> - *Semiconductor Modeling* By Roy G. Leventhal, Lynne Green, et al.
> - *Node List Tolerance Analysis* By Robert R. Boyd.
> - *MOSFET Modelling with SPICE* By Daniel P. Foty.
> - *Transistor Level Modeling for Analog/RF IC Design* By Wladyslaw Grabinski et al.
> - *SPICE: Practical Device Modeling* By Ron M. Kielkowski.
> - *Mosfet Models for Spice Simulation, Including BSIM3v3 and BSIM4* By William Liu.
> - *Semiconductor Device Modeling with SPICE* By Giuseppe Massobrio and Paolo Antognetti.

Descriptive reviews for many of these books are available at the linked site, as well as a number of uncategorized/unreviewed books.

Comment: just linking to another site is a comment, writing something here, like that list, and then linking your source is a great answer. links do die.

Comment: @Kortuk, I'm new here, wasn't aware of the distinction. Feel free to move / delete my answer if it is inappropriate. I have no desire to cause annoyance. C.

Comment: I am asking if you would edit and improve your answer. No need to remove it. You will get more upvotes the other way.

Comment: I edited a few books in for you.

Comment: @Kortuk - I fixed it.  However, this situation may be different because the link appears to be subject to change.  Therefore, the current answer is just a snapshot.  I agree, though, we need at least a summary of the content of a link.

Answer (score 1):

You are better off with that one or Cadence's documentation.  Other than that one, the other books out there are generally not current with the software.

My experience is more for the Capture side of things; not the Layout side.